# Is there any ways in mongodb acts like SQL "drop column"?

Tags: mongodb

I have some mongodb documents which structure like:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("58c212b06ca3472b902f9fdb"),
  "Auction name": "Building",
  "Estimated price": "23,660,000",
  "Auction result": "success",
  "Url": "https://someurl.htm",
  "match_id":   "someid",
  "Final price": "17,750,000",
  "Area": [
    {
      "Area": "696.77"
    }
  ]
}
```

The "match_id" is used for update query and after that I don't need this entry anymore.
Is there any idea to drop this entry and keep the rest of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simpily using an update query to unset the field like the following

```
db.products.update(
{},
{ $unset: { match_id: "" } }
)
```

Keep in mind that the first set of curly braces has been intentionally left blank so that your update query matches every entry in your collection